# Banno: Identify closed accounts

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

From the docs it seems like, `accountStatus` should indicate if an account is closed or active. But we are always getting accountStatus as unKnown for all our users and accounts. So, I would like to confirm what is the better way to identify a closed account.

`URL: /users/{userId}/accounts`

Comment: Do you have examples of the `x-request-id` from the response headers? It's difficult to narrow down what might be happening without more info.

Comment: "x-request-id"=>"242f3bc57920900b72ed4a9f2e04b69a"

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. For the x-request-id I provided above, accountStatus is unknown, but there is an attribute "active." Do you think I should be able to use that flag to identify a closed account?  I did not see anything about active attribute in the docs.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use the `active` attribute since that is 1) deprecated and 2) meant to be used for determining if an account is hidden or not from view in the Banno apps. Neither of those are really going to answer the question you're actually seeking.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. Can you please look at the above x-request-id and let me know why we are seeing `accountStatus` as unknown?

Comment: Nothing is jumping out from the logs for that `x-request-id`. Just to confirm: the "unknown" value for the `accountStatus` is returned in the response for _ALL_ accounts for _ALL_ users?

Comment: The purpose for that confirmation question is to see if the behavior can be narrowed down to specific `accountId`s or specific `userId`s.

Comment: I don't think it is specific to the userId or an accountId. I see the same thing on all the accounts for all the users.

Comment: It seems as though the `accountStatus` always has the value of "Unknown" for credit unions. Engineering is going to update the docs to reflect this information.

Comment: So, is there any other attribute that could be used to identify closed accounts then?

Comment: Not from Banno's APIs (for credit unions, in particular). You may have to get closer to the Symitar core for that info, e.g. via SymXchange: https://jackhenry.dev/symxchange-api-docs/symxchange-api/symxchange-interface/